# C++ UDP cross-platform, fast library (not boost)

Tags: c++, udp, static-libraries

I'm looking forward to C++, UDP, cross-platform library.

Is there any simply to use and fast (free for commercial purpouse) library?

I want small, independent library, not a part of much biggest or abstract solutions, **boost does not interest me** (and explaining why is not really a topic for question, maybe for forum discussion, but we are off-topic now). Also it would be nice if the library was written in C++ not C-style.

Comment: "boost does not interest me" - you are really missing a lot of fun there.

Comment: [libuv](https://github.com/joyent/libuv) is a C library that supports UDP as well as a few other things. It's quite small and depends only on the standard library and OS-specific libraries which you need anyway.

Comment: Unless you give a good reason why you cannot use boost, (like licensing restrictions, though that seems irrational since the boost license is pretty liberal), your limitations are arbitrary and unapplicable to the real world, so that's why your question was closed, if you are curious.

Comment: @Bartek Um, I don't see anyone "raging" here except you. Please keep your comments at least _slightly_ professional and, if you can't do that, do what I do and draw the line at getting personal.

Comment: @Benjamin - I don't have to give reasons why I don't want to use that or that library, the same way I don't need to give reasons why I don't use C# or Java, Linux or Windows - discussion about it is off-topic for me and I'm really not interested in that arguing about boost. Anyway, I found quite good answer thx to Collin (UDT library), Zoidberg also gave me a good point in the comment. P.S. Still the closing of the question is in your decision, I won't complain about it, see you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try [UDT](http://udt.sourceforge.net/)

It's C-style, but nothing a couple simple wrappers won't fix. It's easy to compile as well.

Answer (score 5):

[Asio](http://think-async.com/)
 is a nice, simple to use, fast, free, independent library.

Comment: I have wrote and bolded that Boost do not interest me. Can't you really accept it? It's my decision. I have asked a question, said about limitations. The "why you don't like Boost" is of topic.

Comment: Asio has a standalone non-boost version.

Comment: Asio is ok, before edited, author suggested Boost, so my first comment was to that one.

Comment: Have you noticed that it's pretty much *the same thing*? Downvoters are really great.